# Web-based annotation tool to mark words as belonging to a predefined class

Tags: web-apps, nlp, annotation, crowdsourcing

I'm looking for a web application (either the third-party hosted or hosted by myself) that can:

- load and display a text
- allow the user to mark a word or a group of words as belonging to a predefined class
- record for each such mark which user did it
- free

If possible:

- open-source
- RDBMS back-end for storing the data

---

Here is my use case to clarify the need: I have 1000 news articles (plain text, written in English), I need to mark among those articles all words or a group of words that express a positive or negative sentiment (i.e. I have 2 classes). I'm going to use Amazon Turk/oDesk/etc. to crowdsource the task, hence the choice for a web interface. I will ask each worker to annotate a subset of those 1000 news articles. Each news articles will be annotated by 3 workers to ensure the annotations' quality.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how easy it would be to embed into Amazon Turk (it's a standalone webapp), but you might want to try [brat](http://brat.nlplab.org/) (brat rapid annotation tool).

- open source (MIT License)
- Among other types of annotations, it supports annotating a span of text with a specific (predefined) class which sounds like it might fit your needs
- supports multiple users (but again, some work might be necessary to tie this into Turk)
- [online demo](http://weaver.nlplab.org/~brat/demo/latest/), [examples](http://brat.nlplab.org/examples.html), [GitHub repo](https://github.com/nlplab/brat)

Answer (score 0):

The development of brat is somehow stalled.

As at the beginning of 2019, I would highly recommend INCEpTION https://inception-project.github.io/

INCEpTION has builtin active learning support and a lot more.